# How to fix electric piano circuit board tracks?

Tags: pcb

Hi I am new so please be gentle.
I have AP80R electric Piano with some keys which are intermittent.
I have opened it up and it appears that the board has some signs of corrosion.

I have cleaned it and would appreciate next steps.
Whether broken tracks can be repaired by applying conductive glue?
how to identify where faults are?

I have attached a photo[image]

Thank you

Pit

Comment: Just solder thin wires (like these used for wire-wrapped circuits)  to bypass the broken conductors.

Comment: If I run conductive glue over the brownish tracks, will that help?

Comment: Depends on the glue, I guess. I suggest you go to YouTube and find some repair videos by "8-bit keys" and others. Watch and learn. Come back when you've got the basics down.

Comment: No way to tell. Conductive glue might have too much electrical resistance and not connect the signals properly, and if you touch one track on another might be a nightmare to find out (i.e. high resistance intermittent glitches).

Comment: Thanks, I 'll check our relevant you tube videos. so would you say that soldering thin wires to bypass the broken ones are best solution for now?

Comment: Would you solder thin wires just on brownish / damaged tracks?

Comment: Ah those crazy drunken nights sat around a piano singing and spilling vodka over the piano. Those were the days.

Comment: Andy. I bet you are right. I have bought the piano second hand recently. The boards have screws. Can they be replaced? I have watched the you tube videos incl "8 bit keys" but do not have solder kit, tools etc

Comment: Eugene, do you mean wire wrap similar to the one on last photo , link https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/workshop/techtip/wirewrap.html